# Is using single letters as field names recommendable to in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to use Google Cloud Firestore as the database for my project but before I add it to my app, I would like to know if using single letters as field names to save storage instead of using informative ones (e.g. 'n' instead of 'user_name') is recommended.

Comment: Ultimately it all comes down to personal/team preference, but I think most people would prefer using names that actually make it clear what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation on the storage size calculations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size), it will save on bytes stored per document.  But I don't recommend this, as you're making your database and code less readable at the expense of a very small savings in size.